# Data retrieval from android database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-layout

This is my code for reading the data from my database. Here I'm just receiving the values and printing them using "Toast" class.

```
public void onClickLogin(View btnLogin)
{
    String email,password;
    String[] cols = new String[] {DataBase_Server.EMAIL, DataBase_Server.PASS};
    EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    EditText edtLoginId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    DataBase_Server database=new DataBase_Server(login.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db=database.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.query(DataBase_Server.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    //startManagingCursor(c);
    c.moveToFirst();
    email=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Server.EMAIL));
    password=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Server.PASS));
    Toast.makeText(this,email+" hello "+password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

There are no syntax errors in the code but when I'm running my app and click on my login button I get a force close dialog box which ultimately quits my app and in the "logcat" I see some exception like "Unable to open stack file ......access denied" etc. etc.

logcat:

```
09-20 01:28:55.524: E/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-20 01:28:55.524: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
09-20 01:28:55.524: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
09-20 01:28:55.564: E/dalvikvm(378): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
09-20 01:45:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
  09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
    09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
     09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
      09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
    09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
     09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
      09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
     09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
   09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
  09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):   at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):    at com.example.curbrain.login.onClickLogin(login.java:36)
   09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
     09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):     ... 21 more
   09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
   09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408):   ... 25 more
    09-20 01:45:58.325: E/dalvikvm(408): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

XML CODE :

```
android:onClick="onClickLogin"
```

Comment: When you post code or a LogCat in your question, please use the code format (Ctrl+K).

Comment: Is there more to the LogCat? Also please post where you define the OnClickListener as well (either in XML or Java).

Comment: @rick always ignore that `stack trace file permission denied` line in your LogCat its a false error. Its basically saying it cant save some Logging to the SD card because you don't have write permissions, but this is totally irrelevant to your original error *in nearly all circumstances*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to reference your XML login EditText but you've actually used the ID of an Button:

```
 EditText edtLoginId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
```

Therefore you cannot cast the view returned (a Button) to an EditText

That id is for a button: `R.id.btnLogin` check your XML for the correct ID.

The line explaining it in your LogCat is:

```
 09-20 01:45:58.295: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. There is a capitalization difference between:

```
android:onClick="onClickLogin"
```

And:

```
public void OnClickLogin(View btnLogin)
```

Change your method to a lowercase "o":

```
public void onClickLogin(View btnLogin)
```

---

I see you that updated the question to fix this typo, but have you checked if it is in your code?

Comment: Yeah he has Sam, see his previous SO question.

Comment: Ha! I was referring to the code on the OP's computer which none of use can see from here, not the code in the question. While this error also throws an IllegalStateException, it is caused by a NoSuchMethodException. Good catch with the ClassCast Blundell!